# Start EventService when import impex in Hybris PrepareInterceptor

Tags: java, events, interceptor, sap-commerce-cloud

I have to import an Impex what contains 3 string and one boolean. The logic is like that, if that boolean field is true then in my PrepareInterceptor I will take the values and I try to start my custom event with publishEvent() method. My event is good because I use it in another place, but my problem is the next. After I start to debug to see what is the problem, I see that when I arrive on the line where the publishEvent() is, the event just not trigger. What exactly can be the problem? Thank's!

Comment: Hi @Robert Please share sample code then will able to understand ,what's the issue.
are you getting any exception in console

Comment: I see the problem start after I call the publishEvent(), when I arrived on this method

Comment: @Override
 protected boolean shouldHandleEvent(final NewsletterEvent event)
 {
  final BaseSiteModel site = event.getSite();
  ServicesUtil.validateParameterNotNullStandardMessage("event.site", site);
  return SiteChannel.B2C.equals(site.getChannel());
 }

Comment: When i try to start the process from PrepareInterceptor, I saw that site is null, that is the problem, and in console throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter event.site can not be null

Comment: When the process is started from a controller, site intercept "CMSSite" . What can I do? @RaushanKumar

Comment: I think in your scenario, just call CMSSiteService and set the current site.
CMSSiteService--->getCurrentSite()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting site null in event then try to implement custom logic to set site on current event object.

CMSSiteService--->getCurrentSite()

Comment: I used getBaseSiteForUID(). Thank you, I solved this!

Comment: I have a question, it is possible to get the values for each row in a Init Interceptor when I import an impex?

Comment: Just try to override this method onInitDefaults  there I guess you can pass the unsaved model. Please try if you are getting values or not

Answer (score 1):

The cron job session context isn't associated with any base site, so it may come as null when importing an impex. In your event listener, try setting the base site if it is null;

**youreventlistener.class**

```
@Resource
private BaseSiteService baseSiteService;

    if(baseSiteService.getCurrentBaseSite() == null) {
        baseSiteService.setCurrentBaseSite("yourSiteName",true);
    }
```